# Profile mapping

Tags: quiz

I am using the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module to create multichoice questions quizes.

I have taxonomy terms as Profile and each question is mapped to a profile using custom codes.

Now I want to display the result (One of the profile) according to the combination of options selected by the user at the end of the quiz.

Any help?